# Radon-Nikodym property

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I am currently struggling with the following:

Let $\nu,\mu$ be finite measures on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}) ~$with$~ \nu \ll \mu$ and $f:=\frac{d\nu}{d(\mu+\nu)}$. I would like to show that: 
1.) $f$ exists
2.) $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=\frac{f}{1-f} ~\mu-$a.e. holds.

Help would be gratefully acknowledged. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $\nu\ll\mu+ \nu$. To see that assume $\nu(A)+\mu(A)=0$, then $\mu(A)=0$ and $\nu(A)$ since a measure is nonnegative. So by Radon-Nykodym $f$ exists.

We need to show that for all measurable $A$ one has:
\begin{align}
\nu (A) = \int_A \frac{f}{1-f}\,d\mu
\end{align}
Notice that:
$$\nu(A) = \int_A f \,d\mu + \int_A f\,d\nu =\int_A f\,d\mu + \int_A f\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\,d\mu = \int_A \left( 1+\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)f \,d\mu$$
This means that:
\begin{align}
\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} = \left( 1+\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}\right)f
\end{align}
Hence:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\nu}{d\mu} = \frac{f}{1-f}
\end{align*}
Exactly what we wanted to show.